# Pushing and Popping View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a navigation view controller which is a table view and then from the table view if i select a row it goes into detail view page. When i go to the detail view page i retrieve some information from the server and if the server does not respond then i get an alert view pop up which appears in front of my parent navigation view. now when press ok on the alert view and click on another row and it does go into my "didselectview" method but does not go to my detail view page. Would anyone know why? Code given below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
Item *selectedItem = (Item *)[self.fetchedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString * urlString = [CONST_FEED_DISCRIPTION_URL stringByAppendingString:selectedItem.guid];
NSDate * dateString = selectedItem.date;
JsonViewController *jsonViewController = [[JsonViewController alloc] initWithURLString:urlString date:dateString];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:nil
                                                              action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:CONST_NAVIGATIONBAR_COLOR];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jsonViewController animated:YES];
[backButton release];
[jsonViewController release];
}
```

The first time around you get the alert view (which is an error message). After that nothing happens when u click on a row. but i know it goes into the method given below. would anyone know why? Does it have something to do with me pushing views? and not popping them?

Comment: Are you trying to load that data synchronously - if so, don't! Are you loading that data in viewDidLoad already - if so, don't - use viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear instead.

Comment: No.. Im loading data asynchronously. and No im not using ViewDidLoad im only using viewWillAppear and not ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Defer the push until the next runLoop, to let the tableView return:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    NSLog(@"Going to push...");
    NSLog(@"...view Controller %@", jsonViewController);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:jsonViewController animated:YES];
    [jsonViewController release];
    NSLog(@"Just pushed %@", jsonViewController);
) );
```

Just to be clear, remove both these lines from the existing code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jsonViewController animated:YES];
[jsonViewController release];
```

Comment: Even though this might do the trick, it most likely just hides an implementation mistake done lower below. There are very few cases were deferring such method-call is to be considered good practice.

Comment: Well, I respectively disagree. Changing the UI - actually swapping out the view - in the middle of a delegate call is never a great idea, and I myself have paid for doing so in the last with all kinds of bizarre results.

Comment: Well that freezes my alertview that appears when server not found. which means i cant do anything after this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm so use to using ARC. I believe the above should work for you - I added some logs that will themselves fail if I missed something.

Comment: Thanks.. but that again freezes my alert message not letting me do anything more. while i see the alertview the background i get is my tableview still. This is probably because im only loading the view when all the delegate methods of retrieving data in the next page have finished executing and since it failed i am still on the parent navigation page with the alert view popping up. Also just pushed doesnt appear.

Comment: @CodeGeek123 it sounds a lot as if viewWillAppear hangs when your server is unreachable.

Comment: How can the user select a tableCell when an alert is in front of the table? That's quite confusing. So yes, if you have an alert showing, you should not be doing anything else to the UI til its been dismissed.

Comment: No what i meant was before implementing your code snippet, the alert view never froze but i had the other problem that i came for initially. and at that moment you have the tableview at the back

Comment: @Till yes im guessing that is the case too. but i dont know how to rectify it.

Comment: You need to post different code. How can the table get selected if the alert is up? Are you selecting it in code? Is the alert behind the table (somehow)? You must be doing something very non-standard to have this situation. Does your alert delegate select the cell in code?